# 403 Forbidden when Deploying asp.net 4.0 MVC 3 site to IIS 7

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, iis-7

So I have an EC2 instance running, the URL
NoWeatherSurprises.com
I have the DNS pointing there, and I set up a new site in IIS 7 and pointed it to a folder.  I used Visual Studios Web Developer 2010 express to publish to this folder.  It now has the binaries and such.

However if I go to NoWeatherSurprises.com I get the welcome to IIS 7 screen.
I'd expect to go to my application
If I navigate to http://noweathersurprises.com/weather/ [weather was the folder I published to under wwwroot]
I get a 403 forbidden.  I have no idea why, I am guessing that it is trying to do a directory listing or something instead of launching my MVC Application.

So 2 problems in summary.

1. It is not pointing the domain to the folder directly and I need to add /weather
2. I am getting a 403 forbidden instead of the results of my home controller with the index action.

I am new to IIS 7, I had been using IIS 6 and had a lot less trouble setting it up, but I suspect that's my own fault and i am just missing something.
Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: Is the site you setup in IIS 7 setup to use ASP.NET 4.0 and is it configured to use the integrated (not classic) pipeline?  It sounds like IIS does not know to use MVC routing to launch your site and is looking for a default document (index.html, default.aspx) and cannot find it (which it shouldn't - you are using MVC!)

Answer (score 0):

What did you set your physical path to your website?

On the right hand side in IIS Manager there is 'Basic Settings' where you can see where its pointing.

After you've checked that, make sure the application pool for your website is for v4.0 of the framework. Again in the IIS Manager look under Application Pools, find your website and ensure the framework version is 4.0 (Integrated)

Comment: C:\inetpub\wwwroot\weather
Is the physical path, which corresponds to the proper directory I published to.
Connect as is set to Application User.

I hit test settings though and I get Authentication passes.

Authorization however [Need a new comment it's too big to paste in this one]

Comment: The server is configured to use pass-through authentication with a built-in account to access the specified physical path. However, IIS Manager cannot verify whether the built-in account has access. Make sure that the application pool identity has Read access to the physical path. If this server is joined to a domain, and the application pool identity is NetworkService or LocalSystem, verify that <domain>\<computer_name>$ has Read access to the physical path. Then test these settings again.

Comment: Under basic settings it shows for Application Pool 
ASP.NET v4.0

Comment: under Application Pool -> Advanced Settings (for your app pool) what is the value of the Identity field (under Process Model) ?

Comment: see this link http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/624/application-pool-identities/ and the Section halfway down 'Securing Resources' - remember to enter the user as IIS AppPool\<yourapppool>