# ASP.net MVC4 and Razor :Get 403 error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, razor, http-status-code-403

I have the same problem like this :
[403 Forbidden when Deploying asp.net 4.0 MVC 3 site to IIS 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10166528/403-forbidden-when-deploying-asp-net-4-0-mvc-3-site-to-iis-7)

I'm in the same configuration. When i work on my computer and i heat `F5`, it's ok, the website is visible with this url : `localhost:8754`

But when i try to go on it by the network, i've a `403` error.

I'm running under `IIS7` with and my pool application is `4.0`.

My website is the example create by `VS2012`. I don't change anything on it.

Comment: I've add this line in "system.webServer" in my config file but is it safe?
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>

Answer (score 1):

add this to your web.config

```
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"></modules>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="UrlRoutingHandler"/>
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
```

http://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/introduction-to-iis/iis-modules-overview#Precondition